# Laser level device and theory

Tags: lasers

Does anybody know good book/site explained device types and theory of laser levels?
I only find information like marketing or homemade tuning instructions.

Comment: Instead of asking for a book, you can ask your question here for an immediate answer. What have you found out that you have questions about?

Comment: It's not a specific question, I want to find a book with descriptions of various designs, their advantages and disadvantages, settings, etc.

Comment: Look on Wikipedia for "laser safety" and go from there...